# Shifting sets of numbers after rows are dropped out in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data table:

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), v = 1:8)

   id v
1:  1 1
2:  1 2
3:  2 3
4:  2 4
5:  3 5
6:  3 6
7:  4 7
8:  4 8
```

When I drop the rows with id = 2, I get the following:

```
dt <- dt[id != 2]

   id v
1:  1 1
2:  1 2
3:  3 5
4:  3 6
5:  4 7
6:  4 8
```

At this point, how could I shift the values in `id` so that there is no gap in the integer values in `id`, like the following?

```
   id v
1:  1 1
2:  1 2
3:  2 5
4:  2 6
5:  3 7
6:  3 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update by reference rows by a combination of a logical condition( `id>2`) and `:=` operator:

```r
df[get('id')>2, c('id') := get('id')-1]
```

In English terms: on rows with id>2, replace id by id-1.

By the way, I put column names into string because if latter you want to generalize this function using id<-2, you will need to do `df[get('id')>id, c('id') := get('id')-1]`. In your case it's extra formalism but you might find that useful later

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of options :

1) Using `match`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, id := match(id, unique(id))]
dt

#   id v
#1:  1 1
#2:  1 2
#3:  2 5
#4:  2 6
#5:  3 7
#6:  3 8
```

2) With `factor`

```
dt[, id := as.integer(factor(id))]
```

EDIT: The above two methods by Ronak Shah are faster than the method in the accepted answer:

```
microbenchmark(
          match = {
            dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), v = 1:8)
            dt <- dt[id != 2]
            dt[, id := match(id, unique(id))]},
          factor = {
            dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), v = 1:8)
            dt <- dt[id != 2]
            dt[, id := as.integer(factor(id))]},
          subtract = {
            dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), v = 1:8)
            dt <- dt[id != 2]
            dt[get('id')>2, c('id') := get('id')-1]}
        )

Unit: microseconds
     expr     min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    match 510.401 538.3515 559.029 556.6010 578.0505  625.000   100 a  
   factor 564.402 585.0515 608.497 604.0015 622.2505  831.301   100  b 
 subtract 664.201 693.5510 724.059 716.6005 743.5515 1317.701   100   c
```

Comment: These two methods are faster than the method in the accepted answer.  Sorry I accepted the answer before I saw your answer.

Comment: You are welcome, you can accept whichever answer works best for you. Also for benchmark it is better to benchmark on a bigger dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that should be fast. Note: all of these methods assume the `ID` column is sorted.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), v = 1:8)
dt <- dt[id != 2]
dt[, id := cumsum(c(1L, diff(id) != 0L))]
dt
```

And a couple of more:

```
###rleid
dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), v = 1:8)
dt <- dt[id != 2]
dt[, id := rleid(id)]

###Rcpp
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "
  IntegerVector re_index(IntegerVector x){
  IntegerVector out(x.size());
  int ind = 1;
  out(0) = ind;

  for (int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++) {
    if (x(i) != x(i-1)) ind++;
    out(i) = ind;
  }
  return(out);
}"
)

dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), v = 1:8)
dt <- dt[id != 2]
dt[, id := re_index(id)]
```